# How create output csv with julia?

Tags: julia

I'm new user of Julia.
I try to create one code for an start up.

```
begin
    using Pkg
    Pkg.add("CSV") 
    Pkg.add("DataFrames")  
    using Statistics
    using DataFrames
    using CSV
    using Dates
    v=[1:12]
    resultat=CSV.File("ResultatPropre.csv";header=true; delim=";")
    println(resultat)
    i=1
    while i <= 12
        a=now()     ##Dates.millisecond
        dt = CSV.read(resultat[i,1]*"_"*resultat[i,2]*"_"*resultat[i,3]*"_"*resultat[i,4]*"_1.csv")
        x=resultat[i,6]
        moy="MOYENNE"
        if x==moy
            for c in eachcol(dt)
                println(mean(dt[:c]))
            end 
        else
            for c in eachcol(dt)
                println(median(dt[:c]))
            end
        end 
        v[i]=now()-a
        close(dt)
        i = i + 1 
    end
    CSV.write("OUT1.csv",  DataFrame(hcat(resultat,v)), writeheader=false)
    close(resultat)
end
```

I don't know if this code is correct but i haven't error message.
The document OUT1.CSV is empty.
Why?

Sorry if you can't understand I'm not fluent in english.
Thank you.

Comment: ooops, panic! try to copy-paste your code in your question. Use the button "insert code" or just use the 4 spaces :)

Comment: It is hard to comment on your code, as you have shared an image, but I see at least three places in the code that should throw an exception, so in general the answer is that your result is empty, because the code threw an exception. If you share the input file and the code as @Leos313 suggest we can help you fix it.

Comment: however, have you tried to "debug"? maybe using the simple old-fashion method "print", or executing the code line by line and so on

Comment: This is like you want? @Bogumił Kamiński

Answer (score 1):

As with your previous question this is hard to debug, as it relies on files that are stored on your local machine - it is easiest for others to help you if you can create minimal working examples that reproduce the error you're getting.

From what you posted, there is an obvious issue though with what you're trying to do:

```
resultat=CSV.File("ResultatPropre.csv";header=true; delim=";")
```

This will return a `CSV.File` object, and not a DataFrame as you might expect. Consider the following example:

```
julia> using DataFrames, CSV

julia> CSV.write("out.csv", DataFrame(rand(5, 2))) # example data
"out.csv"

julia> resultat = CSV.File("out.csv")
5-element CSV.File{false}:
 CSV.Row{false}: (x1 = 0.8579220366916582, x2 = 0.6209363986752581)
 CSV.Row{false}: (x1 = 0.25341118271903995, x2 = 0.13828085618933872)
 CSV.Row{false}: (x1 = 0.67532944746357, x2 = 0.7830459406731047)
 CSV.Row{false}: (x1 = 0.268297279369758, x2 = 0.9701649420771219)
 CSV.Row{false}: (x1 = 0.8369770803698637, x2 = 0.77439272213442)
```

This is probably not what you expected, given that you `hcat` `resultat` and your `v` vector later on.

The line that will actually error in your code however is:

```
close(dt)
```

At this point, `dt` is a `DataFrame`, as you've created it by calling `CSV.read` on a csv file, and you are calling the `close` function on this DataFrame. However, a `close` method does not exist for DataFrames:

```
julia> close(DataFrame(rand(5,2)))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching close(::DataFrame)
```

The result of `CSV.read` is a `DataFrame` that is stored in memory, and there is no "open" file handle anywhere that needs to be closed after performing operations on your DataFrame - `CSV.read` is different from calling `open` on some text file that you then iterate through.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I need one other information.
In my code i try to count time between tow dates.
Do you know how do this?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need one other information. In my code i try to count time between tow dates. Do you know how do this?